# How to pass data with an Ajax request to Flask application?

Tags: ajax, flask

I can not send datas with an Ajax (post) request to my Flask application :

In the data.html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
   url: '{{ url_for("data_page") }}',
   type: "post",
   data: {
     timeDelta: "Mydata",
   },
 });
});
</script>
```

The flask app :

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data_page():

    if request.method == "POST":
        
        timedelta = request.args.get('timeDelta')
        print(timedelta) # ==========>  Why it is None ?
       
    return render_template("data.html")
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the query string arguments with `request.args.get` but you did a POST request so the data will be in `request.args.form('timeDelta')`